# How to remove text "Log In" from login page

Tags: theme-development, admin, login

I am using Theme My Login and have noticed that, even though I am customising my own `login-form.php` template and simply including the appropriate form on a blank page with `theme_my_login();`, the text `Log In` is always appearing and is *not even in a selectable DOM element*:

```
Log In
<div class="login" id="theme-my-login1">
  <form name="loginform" id="loginform1" action="http://domain/login/" method="post" target="_blank">
  ...
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to remove this 'Log In' text? I'm not sure where it is coming from.

I've also tried hooking `login_headertitle` as in this [Codex Article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Change_the_Login_Logo).

Comment: That looks to be the right file, best I can tell. Are you sure your custom `login-form.php` is loaded? Maybe put `hello world` in it just to be sure?

Comment: @Pat Yes the custom code is loaded, I've modified it a fair bit and the changes are appearing. I'm confused because the text "Log In" appears nowhere in the `Theme My Login` block nor the page template. I'm thinking I can catch the output to an output buffer and strip the text "Log In", but that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: I have a local dev site and a production site. At present my TML works perfectly on my local site. On my production server I get the extra "Log In" text and the id for the form has changed from loginform to loginform1, which is the same as yours.

Answer (score 4):

Use shortcode:

```
[theme-my-login show_title=0]
```

or function:

```
<?php theme_my_login( array( 'default_action' => 'login', 'show_title' => '0') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use CSS to hide it:

```
#theme-my-login1 #header-element {
 display:none;
}
```

Add to the login page by using a function / filter e.g.

```
function custom_login_css() {
 echo '<style type="text/css">#theme-my-login1 #header-element {
 display:none;}</style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_css');
```

Answer (score 1):

Welp the filter provided in the Wordpress forums won't seem to work either. I'm on multi-site.

// Change the Theme My Login Login Template Header

`function tml_title_filter( $title, $action ) {
    if ( 'login' == $action )
        return 'Login / Register';
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'tml_title', 'tml_title_filter', 10, 2 );`

Ok, found the relevant doc here:

http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/changing-page-titles/

Watch out for the error in the code:

`$user = wp_get_current_user;`

should be:

`$user = wp_get_current_user();`

Comment: The docs above provide a function that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. This is how I fixed it...

Pass `$args = array( 'show_title' => false );` as a parameter.

So yo would have something like this:

`// arguments for Theme My Login`

`$args = array( 'show_title' => false );`

`Theme_My_Login( $args );`

I was showing the login form in a modal so I used this to add the login form without the title.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the title completely from all the forms:

```
function tml_title( $title, $action ) {
    $title = '';
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'tml_title', 'tml_title', 11, 2 );
```

Comment: It would also remove "forget password link text & register link text. Please take care about it

Answer (score -1):

For those looking for this in the future... In the includes folder, in the `class-theme-my-login-template.php` and go to

```
public function get_title()
```

Then in the `default` `case` in the `switch` statement, replace `$title = __( 'Log In' );` with `$title = __( '' );`.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to modify core files?

Comment: -1 for this answer. You should **NEVER** change core/theme/plugin templates. It is extremely bad practice. This is what [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) are for